# Helping/explanatory notes for Landau&Lifschitz Physics Course

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I've recently restored my interest on theoretical physics (I have a master degree in Electrical Engineering) and began my study with first volume of the Physics Course by Landau and Lifshitz. This is a very good and interesting book, and it just blows my mind (both in a positive and negative ways) - you spend really a lot of time trying to understand everything out of this textbook. Maybe someone can suggest somewhat sort of helping sidenotes for this book?

Comment: Have you tried googling for someone's notes? I find that usually very helpful if I find it ofc :D L&L is very advanced and mathematically rigorous imo. Have you tried Goldstein's Classical Mechanics? That was recommended book when I was taking classical mechanics in my uni :)

Comment: For your situation I highly recommend the video lecture series http://theoreticalminimum.com/

Comment: One of the first results on google: http://lantonov.tripod.com/

Comment: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html